need help adding a procedural mesh to scene in irrlicht
ive gone through every route including chatgpt to find out why my code fails when i try to add this mesh to a scene node, ive tried addoctreescenenode and addmeshscenenode and they both fail, so its the mesh, but all checks i do in the generatemesh function pass and all variables in the mesh show they are not empty, but it still fails, calling an access error and throws irrlichts debug breakpoint if index is used in the irrArray.h file.
if i remove all the buffers and just run one buffer that ignores blocktypes it works fine.
if i use all the buffers and assign the verts and indices to their respective buffer it fills the buffer and the function returns a mesh that i can check all aspects like the buffer count, size and contents of its vertices and indices, what material type it has, and what texture is on the material, but i cant DO anything with it. switching it to IMesh breaks everything to the point i have to redo almost all code that deals with my terrain.
SMesh* Terrain::GenerateMesh(Chunk& chunk){

const vector<Chunk::Vertex>& vertices = chunk.vertices;
const vector<u16>& indices = chunk.indices;

SMeshBuffer* grassBuffer = new SMeshBuffer();
SMeshBuffer* dirtBuffer = new SMeshBuffer();
SMeshBuffer* rockBuffer = new SMeshBuffer();
SMeshBuffer* bedrockBuffer = new SMeshBuffer();


for (u16 i = 0; i < indices.size(); ++i) {
    u16 ix = indices[i];  // Get index from the indices vector

    // Check if the index is within the bounds of the vertices vector
    if (ix < vertices.size()) {
        // Access the vertex using the index
        Chunk::Vertex vertex = vertices[ix];

        // Handle the block types based on a more explicit comparison
        switch (vertex.type) {
        case Chunk::BLOCKTYPE::Grass:
            grassBuffer->Vertices.push_back(S3DVertex(vertex.position, vertex.normal, vertex.color, vertex.texCoords));
            grassBuffer->Indices.push_back(ix);
            break;
        case Chunk::BLOCKTYPE::Dirt:
            dirtBuffer->Vertices.push_back(S3DVertex(vertex.position, vertex.normal, vertex.color, vertex.texCoords));
            dirtBuffer->Indices.push_back(ix);
            break;
        case Chunk::BLOCKTYPE::Rock:
            rockBuffer->Vertices.push_back(S3DVertex(vertex.position, vertex.normal, vertex.color, vertex.texCoords));
            rockBuffer->Indices.push_back(ix);
            break;
        case Chunk::BLOCKTYPE::BedRock:
            bedrockBuffer->Vertices.push_back(S3DVertex(vertex.position, vertex.normal, vertex.color, vertex.texCoords));
            bedrockBuffer->Indices.push_back(ix);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    else {
        // Print additional debug information if the index is invalid
        printf("Invalid index: %d (Index exceeds vertices size of %zu)\n", ix, vertices.size());
    }
}

printf("GrassBuffer vertices: %i, indices: %i\n", grassBuffer->Vertices.size(), grassBuffer->Indices.size());
printf("DirtBuffer vertices: %i, indices: %i\n", dirtBuffer->Vertices.size(), dirtBuffer->Indices.size());
printf("RockBuffer vertices: %i, indices: %i\n", rockBuffer->Vertices.size(), rockBuffer->Indices.size());
printf("BedrockBuffer vertices: %i, indices: %i\n", bedrockBuffer->Vertices.size(), bedrockBuffer->Indices.size());

SMesh* mesh = new SMesh();

if(grassBuffer->Vertices.size() > 0)
{
    grassBuffer->Material.MaterialType = video::EMT_SOLID;
    grassBuffer->getMaterial().setTexture(0, grassTexture);
    mesh->addMeshBuffer(grassBuffer);
}
if(dirtBuffer->Vertices.size() > 0)
{
    dirtBuffer->Material.MaterialType = video::EMT_SOLID;
    dirtBuffer->getMaterial().setTexture(0, dirtTexture);
    mesh->addMeshBuffer(dirtBuffer);
}
if(rockBuffer->Vertices.size() > 0)
{
    rockBuffer->Material.MaterialType = video::EMT_SOLID;
    rockBuffer->getMaterial().setTexture(0, rockTexture);
    mesh->addMeshBuffer(rockBuffer);
}
if(bedrockBuffer->Vertices.size() > 0)
{
    bedrockBuffer->Material.MaterialType = video::EMT_SOLID;
    bedrockBuffer->getMaterial().setTexture(0, bedrockTexture);
    mesh->addMeshBuffer(bedrockBuffer);
}
mesh->recalculateBoundingBox();

grassBuffer->drop();
dirtBuffer->drop();
rockBuffer->drop();
bedrockBuffer->drop();

return mesh;

}

Side note : Including "chatgpt"... ehr no that is not a good resource (and definitely not a last resort).

i realized that after it kept changing my code into worse code that had alot of erros

Your real problem is that you use new in your function and do not model ownership of the  SMeshBuffer's they reall should be members of your class (probably not even pointers). If you still feel you need pointers/new then use std::make_unique

Haha yes "ChatGPT" is a generic large language model and it really doesn't know programming very well. Python might be a bit predictable but C++ is far beyond what ChatGpt can handle.

I have not use "Irrlicht" itself.. but it seems to have tutorials : https://irrlicht.sourceforge.io/docu/example001.html did you work through them first?  But also before you do that work through "learncpp.com" so you also know a bit more about how C++ actually works.  Then look at "cppreference.com" if you want to lookup what C++ has to offer (e.g. std::vector and the like). And finally at least scan the C++ core guidelines it has a few things to say about raw pointers and use of new/delete

sorry should have mentioned im coming from unity c#, im learning C++ and so far most translations are the same, i didnt know this though.

C++ is really not like C#.  For C++ you really need to think differently specifically about the lifecycle of objects. In C++ scopes are very very important. I already had the feeling you were new at C++, so yes really start learning C++ from scratch (and kind of forget how C# works)

C++ and C# are hugely different languages. C# is garbage collected, C++ has destructors and value semantics. There really is no comparison, and any attempt to program C++ like it was C# is going to fail.

Most importantly learn about the difference between "reference semantics" (mostly used in C#) and "value semantics" (often used in C++, but with pointers/references you also get "reference semantics) in C++)

@john C++ can do reference semantics too, but it is an explicit option (where ok, the references/pointers have value semantics)

My guess would be that grassBuffer->Indices.push_back(ix) should be grassBuffer->Indices.push_back(grassBuffer->vertices.size()-1), ix is the index to your original vertex list, not the index into your new vertex buffers

@PepijnKramer I believe C# can do value semantics too (on a type by type basis). So I think the accurate statement is that value semantics are the default in C++ and reference semantics are the default in C#. In any case the point is that one has to be aware of the differences when moving from C# to C++.

@Alan Birtles
thanks! i cant believe i missed that, its always the small things.

Well that's the indexing issue... but the larger issues still remain. With your current code you will have (a lot of) memory leaks and possibly crashes

@john I agree that is a fair summary :)

@PepijnKramer note that irrlicht uses reference counting so there aren't memory leaks in this code https://irrlicht.sourceforge.io/docu/classirr_1_1_i_reference_counted.html (though a RAII wrapper which automatically calls drop would make the code safer)

Ah ok, but that is "surprising" from a C++ point of view (std::shared_ptr would have been more clear). But I stand corrected it seems this API works that way (which in my opinion drops a few points in being "well-designed" for C++)

@PepijnKramer Looks like it started in 2002, it's not necessarily bad, just old and difficult to update without breaking everyone's code

grassBuffer->Indices.push_back(ix) should be grassBuffer->Indices.push_back(grassBuffer->vertices.size()-1), ix is the index to your original vertex list, not the index into your new vertex buffers
